# How do you determine if you are on the first or last line of text in a textarea?

Tags: javascript

I need to determine if a user is on the first line, or last line, of text in a textarea.

The reason for this is that the client has requested that when a user presses the up arrow while on the top line of text in a textarea they are taken to the previous form field, or if on the last line of text and pressing the down arrow the user is taken to the following form field.

I have found a way to determine which row of text the cursor is on, but it only works if the rows of the textarea are defined.  Most of the the textarea's on the page are using the jQuery TextAreaExpander plugin, so their rows are not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following combination of HTML and JavaScript works for me in Chrome:

HTML:

```
<input id="bta"><br><br>
<textarea id="ta" cols="10" rows="2"></textarea><br><br>
<input id="ata">
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var $ata = $('#ata'),
        $bta = $('#bta'),
        $ta = $('#ta');

    $ta.bind('keyup', function(e) {
        if (this.selectionStart === 0 && e.keyCode === 38) {
            $bta.val('Going up!').focus();
            $ata.val('');
        } else if (this.selectionStart === this.value.length && e.keyCode === 40) {
            $ata.val('Going down!').focus();
            $bta.val('');
        }
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jsumners/DqSLS/)

In this example I am relying on an HTML5 property: [selectionStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTextAreaElement). I do not know if this will work in older browsers.

Comment: If only I had realized that the cursor moved to the beginning or end of the line when on the first or last row when you move up or down this would have been much less of a pain.  Thank you for the code.

Luckily I don't have to worry about older browsers, so the solution is beautiful.

Comment: It doesn't work if your cursor is at the beginning of the second line and you press UP arrow (adequately it doesn't work if you are at the end of penultimate line and press DOWN arrow)). Therefore @kennebec answer is better, because it works in every case.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the cursor position on keydown, find the indexOf the previous (up arrow) or next (down arrow) newline character. If -1, go to the previous or next field.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @James solution doesn't work in every case - I have described it in comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681426/how-do-you-determine-if-you-are-on-the-first-or-last-line-of-text-in-a-textarea/7681684#comment123322071_7681684)